# How to open a connection with flags using the rusqlite crate?

Tags: sqlite, rust

I read the following in the [rusqlite](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.13.0/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html) documentation:

> `Connection::open(path)` is equivalent to `Connection::open_with_flags(path, SQLITE_OPEN_READ_WRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE)`.

I copied that into the the following simple code:

```
extern crate rusqlite;
use rusqlite::Connection;

fn main() {
    let path = "/usr/local/data/mydb.sqlite";
    let conn = Connection::open_with_flags(path, SQLITE_OPEN_READ_WRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
}
```

I actually want to replace those flags with `SQLITE_OPEN_READ_ONLY`, but figured this was a good place to start.

I get the following errors:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `SQLITE_OPEN_READ_WRITE` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:50
  |
6 |     let conn = Connection::open_with_flags(path, SQLITE_OPEN_READ_WRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
  |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` in this scope
 --> src/main.rs:6:75
  |
6 |     let conn = Connection::open_with_flags(path, SQLITE_OPEN_READ_WRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
  |                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

It seems I'm missing something like `use rusqlite::Something;`, but what is that something? I was unable to figure out.

I have the following in my `Cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies.rusqlite]
version = "0.13.0"
features = ["bundled"]
```

Comment: Based on your original error message style, you *really* should upgrade your version of Rust. Rust has new releases every 6 weeks, and Rust 1.24.0 is the most recent.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Actually, I use a fairly new version, which is 1.22.1. On the console, I get much more verbose error messages. But, I use sublime text 3 as my editor and the rust enhanced package. I copied my error messages from there. I guess that the rust enhanced package simplifies the error message on its output window. It does properly highlight the problematic parts though, so that I actually don't lose the additional information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is equivalent to `Connection::open_with_flags`

You should look at the [`open_with_flags` documentation](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.13.0/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html#method.open_with_flags):

```
fn open_with_flags<P: AsRef<Path>>(
    path: P, 
    flags: OpenFlags
) -> Result<Connection>
```

Then click through to [`OpenFlags`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.13.0/rusqlite/struct.OpenFlags.html). This defines [your flag](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/0.13.0/rusqlite/struct.OpenFlags.html#associatedconstant.SQLITE_OPEN_READ_ONLY) as an *associated constant*:

```
const SQLITE_OPEN_READ_ONLY: OpenFlags
```

All together:

```
extern crate rusqlite;

use rusqlite::{Connection, OpenFlags};

fn main() {
    let path = "/usr/local/data/mydb.sqlite";
    let conn = Connection::open_with_flags(path, OpenFlags::SQLITE_OPEN_READ_ONLY);
}
```